# git dreamweaver/cfbuilder/eclipse local history

Tags: eclipse, git, coldfusion, dreamweaver, coldfusionbuilder

looking solution for code local history in dreamweaver/cfbuilder. we are using Git-Hub for version controlling. I don't know if I can using git-hub for local history in dreamwearer or cfbuilder.

I was googling and found {https://github.com/vishr/local-history}. look like. it is for Atom IDE but we are use dreamwearver & cfbuilder. if some have any idea if I can enable these two Editors local history it will be great help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that CFBuilder will have a plug-in for git.  Since CFBuilder is a version of Eclipse; this plug-in will probably work:

http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

I do use DreamWeaver and here is a plug-in that integrates git:

https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver/

UPDATE:

I'm sorry.  Adobe stopped development on the Adobe Extension Manager CC for CC 2015+.  It will not work with newer versions of DreamWeaver CC.  I did have Adobe Extension Manager CC version 7.3.2.29 installed.  The version that you can download from Adobe's web site is 7.2.1.6.  Neither of these versions work with DreamWeaver CC 2017

https://www.adobeexchange.com/resources/27

Adobe doesn't appear to offer an alternative for installing extensions.

I did find an Extension Manager that works with DreamWeaver CC 2017 on the DMX Zone web site.

https://www.dmxzone.com/go/22670/dmxzone-extension-manager-for-dreamweaver/#

You can use it to install the extension (and refresh the installed extension list to get it to appear).  However, the extension does not appear in DreamWeaver at all.  So, even though it is "installed" it doesn't do anything.

At this point, I would recommend using something else that is not integrated into DreamWeaver CC 2017+.  Adobe seems to going down a path that discourages plug-in/extension development.

I have used gitKraken before and it works pretty well as a graphical git interface.

https://www.gitkraken.com/

Comment: thanks for your response. when im trying  to install "GITWeaver - 1.4.1.zxp"  it shows `"Cannot find required data form database. The extension will not be installed."` Im using DM CC2017